# How to analyze cause of stuck Selenium Execution?

Tags: java, linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I've 375 Selenium tests which run in parallel with 7 threads on `CentOS 7` and machine has 32 GB RAM size. I ran these tests issuing command from Terminal.

And observed that after certain number of tests, next tests are not executed. Test execution has stuck and this might appear in future. To avoid this, I want to identify the cause so I'll fix and next time I won't appear.

I am not sure what steps should be taken to identify the cause. Please help what logs, processes or other details to check to identify why execution has stuck.

Comment: When you say that they are stuck you mean that all 7 threads are stuck at the same time? Also whether they are stuck at a random point or new webdrivers stop being created so that new tests will not even run?

Comment: Yes, all 7 threads stuck at same time and they stuck at random point. There is no issue wtih webdriver or browser as browser was launched and interacted.